# What is this part on RC switch?

Tags: identification

I have a car remote switch and I'm trying to find its frequency band.

I found this part on it :
[image]
 What is this ? I can't find it on the internet by searching the numbers on it's top(601-726S)

Comment: It's a crystal of some sort, even if you could find the frequency of that crystal it may be unrelated to the RF frequency.

Comment: You almost overwrote the part designator Y which means it is a crystal, or given the package and pins, it might be a ceramic resonator.

Comment: Every RF remote will have an FCC ID on it that you can look up the frequency info.

Comment: Yes I miss that symbol , thanks . But is it possible to find its frequency ?

Comment: Given U1 is a Microchip brand device, it probably uses advanced signalling techniques. Even if you knew the frequency, chances are poor of emulating or bypassing this device.

Comment: No it doesn't seems to be an advanced signaling ,I found the sqaure wave signal at one of U1 pins with my scope , also I decode the signal and got a 64bit code that is sent by pushing the switches. Im just trying to find which frequency is this switch using and make a simple receiver for it to see the rf signal in my scope just for fun